# How to parse a string to a ctime struct?

Tags: c++, c, time, strftime, ctime

Is there an established way to parse a string to a Time structure?

What I would ideally like to do is the reverse of `strftime(...)`, where instead of producing a string from a time struct and format string, I get a time struct from a string parsed according to the provided format string.

I would prefer not to add additional overhead by including a DateTime class such as that found in Boost or .NET

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The corresponding method for parsing strings to `struct tm *` is [`strptime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strptime.html).

Unfortunately this isn't part of the standard C runtime library and doesn't exist on e.g. windows, but you can reuse a BSD-licensed version, such as [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/25a654f9-b6b6-490a-8f36-c87483bb36b7).