# Subtract char pointer from time_t

Tags: c, datetime, pointers, strptime

I have date time in character pointer -

```
char *connectTime = "2013-10-19 01:10:00";
```

then I fetched current time that'll be disconnect time.

```
time_t disconnectTime;
disconnectTime = time(NULL);
```

Now, I want to subtract connectTime from disconnectTime. I googled but couldn't implement it.
Please help.

Comment: What you have is a string. You need to parse it into a `time_t` value first.

Comment: how to parse it into time_t ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671859/how-to-parse-a-string-to-a-ctime-struct Is this helpful?

Comment: Read [How to compare two time stamp in format “`Month Date hh:mm:ss`” to check +ve or -ve value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555406/how-to-compare-two-time-stamp-in-format-month-date-hhmmss-to-check-ve-or-v/15556395#15556395)

Comment: Not really a duplicate as here the date/time given in string format shall be substracted from a `time_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`strptime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) to convert `connectTime` to a `struct tm` and then use [`mktime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) on the latter to convert the it to a `time_t`.

```
char * connectTime = "2013-10-19 01:10:00";
struct tm tmConnect = {0};
time_t timeConnect;
char * pc = strptime(connectTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tmConnect);
if ((NULL == pc) || ('\0' != *(pc + strlen(connectTime))) /* The second condition assume connectTime does not hold any more characters after "... 01:10:00". */
{
  perror("strptime() failed");
  /* handle error */
}
else
{
  timeConnect = mktime(&tmConnect);
}
```

To then calculate the difference in seconds use [`difftime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/difftime.3.html), as mentioned by in *[Grijesh Chauhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1673391/grijesh-chauhan)*'s comment:

```
time_t disconnectTime;
disconnectTime = time(NULL);
double diff = difftime(disconnectTime, timeConnect);
```

Comment: And for time diffidence/subtract use: [`double difftime (time_t end, time_t beginning);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/)

Comment: Thanks all for quick response...

Comment: When I am using same code as written above then I am not getting correct difference. Minute is not working like connectTime is "2013-10-19 01:10:00" when i am subtracting then I am getting difference from "01:00:00" not from "01:10:00"

Comment: value of tmConnect is "01:00:00"

Comment: @user2794235: You are correct, there was a typo in the format passed to `strptime()` in my code snippet. I just corrected that.

Comment: @alk Still not getting correct result. This time I am getting "Thu Jan  1 05:30:00 1970" in timeConnect

Comment: @user23750: The format specifier for the seconds was wrong: `%s`. It is `%S`. Corrected after having checked `man strptime`.